Getting file name using pywinauto
I am using pywinauto to automate my desktop apps. When I open the outlook app on my desktop and click on a link, a file is downloaded in the 'Downloads' folder of my desktop. I want to get the file name or absolute path of the file so that I can use it for playback. Is there a way to get the file name?
I created a json with the element_name and control_type to playback the actions. But I can't get the file name when clicking on it.

Well, how about using pyautogui to press windows + e, then examine file explorer? There are better ways - python can show a list of files in a dir ordered by creation date.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@SlightlyKosumi I am recording the actions performed (left click, right click etc.) on my desktop using pywinauto and pyautogui and saving it in a json file. When I click on an element I get the wrapper of the element from pywinauto, which then I use as playback. But when I click on a file, I do not get any id (a wrapper or name), which makes it tougher for me to playback. Is there a way to get file name?

This is the function I am using to get the wrapper:
def get_element_from_point(x, y):     try:         elem = pywinauto.uia_defines.IUIA().iuia.ElementFromPoint(tagPOINT(x, y))         element = pywinauto.uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo(elem)         wrapper = pywinauto.controls.uiawrapper.UIAWrapper(element)         props = wrapper.get_properties()         return {"element_name": props.get('texts', [""])[0], "control_type": element.control_type}     except Exception as e:         # print(f"wrapper not found: {e}")         return {"element_name": "", "control_type": ""}
